# Loading requests.get().text in memory?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm making something where I go to a url (my url), grab lines from the site use `.text.splitlines()`. However I want my program to this quite often and I don't want it to keep making a request everytime (I'd have over a million requests). Is it possible to store the page's contents into memory?

My code:

```
import random, requests

country_list = requests.get("url")
ending = requests.get("url")
presets = [""]

def generate_shopping():
    shopping_begin = requests.get("url")
    shopping_words = requests.get("url")
    return random.choice(shopping_begin.text.splitlines()) + "-" + random.choice(shopping_words.text.splitlines()) + "-" + random.choice(country_list.text.splitlines()) + "-" + random.choice(presets) + "-" + random.choice(ending.text.splitlines())

def output():
    with open("outputs.txt", "w", encoding='utf8') as f:
        for i in range(1000000):
            f.write(generate_shopping() + "\n")

output()
```

Comment: Yes, *you are already storing the pages contents in memory*...

Comment: I'm still sending as many requests as I put in the range() box to my domain

Comment: yeah, because you keep calling the function that makes those requests, and you always discard the contents of those requests.

Comment: so then how'd I go about?

Comment: Don't discard the results? Just like you are doing with `country_list`